# How to change the css of two elements by clicking a class in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my html code :

```
<div class="contentSuma" style="float:left">
   Adauga Suma
</div>
<input type ="text" class ="sumaTransa" style ="display:none;float:left;">
<a href="#" class = "addsumaTransa"  style ="float:left;display:none;">+</a>
```

and the js functino code :

```
$(".contentSuma").click(function() {
        $(this).next('.sumaTransa').css("display","inline");
        $(this).siblings(":a").css("display","inline");
});
```

I want to change the css from class .sumaTransa and a html element by clicking the class .contentSuma . How can i do that ? Why my code doesn't work? Thank you

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: oke thx for mentioned it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed `{` in after function  this line:

```
$(".contentSuma").click(function()
```

remove `:` from  `siblings(":a")` .

see [api doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for jquery selector.

try this:

```
    $(".contentSuma").click(function()  {
        $(this).next('.sumaTransa').css("display","inline");
        $(this).siblings("a").css("display","inline");
});
```

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/52/)

Comment: @Chester: did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need colon `:` to select the sibling anchor here:

```
$(this).siblings("a").css("display","inline");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

Just something different and easy.

```
 $(this).find('.sumaTransa').addclass("newClass");
 $(this).find('.newClass').removeClass("sumaTransa");
```

Looks easy this way!